# Pingfederate kerberos authentication is authenticating any user from any domain

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, openam, pingfederate

I am trying to configured SAML SSO with OpenAM as SP and PingFederate as IDP with SP-Initiated SSO and using Redirect-Post binding. I am using kerberos adapter for implementing SSO.

I have configured Kerberos adapter to use "e-glue.com" domain and provided KDC details in the configuration. I have also added "setspn" of Pingfederate server in domain controller properly.
However when I login to a computer with valid "e-glue.com" user and hit SSO url with "https://hostname.e-glue.com:1912/openam/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?idpEntityID=ent-026330&metaAlias=/sp" it redirects me to IDP and SSO is successful and user gets created in openam.
But if I do the same thing with other domain.. which is not "e-glue.com", it still autheticates the user and user is created in openam.

This is so strange, there is something missing as the user which is not part of e-glue domain though we configured kerberos adapter to use e-glue.com KDC, is getting authenticated. I am missing something, not sure what. 
Please share if you have any information about what is going wrong.

Comment: So, you are logged into the PC as the "other" domain user? And you are being redirected to PingFederate? Looking in the logs (I hope they are set to debug) on PingFederate, do you see the SAML response showing a success or failure? I would suggest adding some logging to this question, because there's simply not enough here to help you figure out where the issue is. You can also open a case with Ping on their support portal, since this is a supported configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because of inter-domain trust relationship.

PingFederate (IDP) is configured to authenticate users via "e-glue.com" domain.

So I logged in to my computer which was in domain "someother.domain".
But this "someother.domain" implemented an Active Directory directory service forest and has trust relationship between "e-glue.com" and itself. So all users logged in to IDP are also VALID users because of trust relationship.
It took me some time to understand this.